# Search and replace shell variable with multiline shell variable

Tags: regex, perl, shell, awk, sed

I know there are lots of similar questions but, I guess because of the formatting of the search/replace variables they are not working for my situation.

The overall script I am working on will read a text file (using combinations of grep and awk) to create two shell variables, $find and $replace.  $find is a single line string containing all manner of characters.  $replace is a multiline string containing all manner of characters.

example:

```
echo "$find"
```

returns

```
type result input1 another_input random_input<10> / name
```

and

```
echo "$replace"
```

returns

```
.TAG name
result input1 random_input / name1
random_input<10> input1 another_input / name2
.NTAG
```

Now I just need to substitute $find with $replace.  I have tried sed and perl but it fails.

Tried (among a lot of other stuff)

```
perl -e -i.bak "s/$find/$replace/g" text.file
perl -e -i.bak 's,"'$find'","'$replace'",g' text.file
perl -e -i.bak "s|$find|$replace|g" text.file
```

and

```
sed -i "s/$find/$replace/g" text.file
```

My guess is the problems are caused by some character in the string being interpreted as special characters.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not exactly, the problem is you are using regexp constructs when what you want to operate on are strings. You cannot do that with sed as it ONLY operates on regexps, I expect perl does have some constructs to handle strings but those would not be the constructs you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for any values of find or replace:

```
$ cat file
foo
type result input1 another_input random_input<10> / name
bar

$ awk -v find="$find" -v replace="$replace" 's=index($0,find){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) replace substr($0,s+length(find))}1' file
foo
.TAG name
result input1 random_input / name1
random_input<10> input1 another_input / name2
.NTAG
bar
```

if `find` is always one whole line it can be simplified, e.g. this might be all you need:

```
$ awk -v find="$find" -v replace="$replace" '$0==find{$0=replace}1' file
foo
.TAG name
result input1 random_input / name1
random_input<10> input1 another_input / name2
.NTAG
bar
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the solution.  Any chance you could explain the syntax used or point me to a reference?

Comment: man awk and look for the index() and substr() functions. Also I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: @Ed Morton: I just try with special char `find='$1';replace='$2'` and no replacement of`$1` in `$2` on my AIX (KSH). Do you think it is due to my shell behaviour or limitation of the awk like in sed ?

Comment: It is not a limitation of awk, nor would any shell I know of have any issue. There is simply nothing special about those characters in strings. Are you setting awk variables or shell variables with those statements? Did you literally want `find` to have the value `$1` (i.e. a dollar sign and then the digit `1`) or did you want it to contain the value of the first positional parameter of the shell (in which case you'd have to use `find="$1"` with double quotes, not single, to allow the shell to expand `$1`) or something else?

Comment: I put the litteral `$1` (and also a `$2` for test) in a line of the texte file and try with the value of find as show (looking litteral `$1` and not content of a first eventual argument). Intersted because this is hard to handle all this kind of special char in sed and need preparation of value before use in sed itself.

Comment: There should be no problem with that. Look: `$ echo 'a$1b' | awk -v o='$1' -v n='$2' 's=index($0,o){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) n substr($0,s+length(o))}1'` outputs `a$2b`. If what you are doing isn't behaving as you'd expect, you're doing something wrong so post a question so we can see what it is and fix it.

Comment: @jbord39 I see from your new question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27927343/1745001 that you are using this solution. Please click on the check mark next to it if this is your accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

restructure your variable to read

```
replace=".TAG name\nresult input1 random_input / name1\nrandom_input<10> input1 another_input / name2\n.NTAG"
```

or restructure it like this

```
replace='.TAG name\
    result input1 random_input / name1\
    random_input<10> input1 another_input / name2\
    .NTAG'
```

Also your delimiter is causing conflict with your variable `replace` characters since there are `/` in your variable

you can try `#` as your delimiter or any other char that is not in your variable

```
 sed "s#$find#$replace#g" text_file
```

Comment: There's a couple dozen ways in which that can fail depending on the contents of `find` and/or `replace`. You cannot do this robustly with sed.

Answer (score 0):

one way with sed, quick and dirty so not bullet proof like the awk of @Ed Morton

```
find_sed="$( printf "%s" "${find}" | sed 's/[^0-9(){}]/\\&/g' )"
replace_sed="$( printf "%s" "${replace}" | sed "s/[&\\]/\\/g;s/\n/\\&/g' )"

sed "s/${find_sed}/${replace_sed}/g" YourFile
```

- Could be a one line with internal substitution instead of variable, but more explicit like this
- posix version ( `--posix` with GNU sed), if not posix, adapt `[^0-9(){}]` depending your special character that use a escape char for special meaning like `\+\n\d\`

Comment: There's many values of `find` and/or `replace` that'd cause that script to fail by either not replacing `find` when it should, or by replacing it with the wrong thing, or by producing a syntax error. I'm not sure that just saying it's not bullet proof captures how fragile it really is and unfortunately it might produce the expected output for some sample input set the OP tests it against so (s)he might think it's a robust solution and then go execute it on their real data and completely mess it up.

Comment: Totaly agree, there is no securisation except direct special char. Securization will depend of several parameter (OS/Sell, source of value) but it will work without lot of problem with data like the provided sample.