# Prepend all lines between two patterns with back-reference

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, sed

I am working on a simple script to prepend part of the pattern match for all lines between matches.

For example:

```
matchline_VAR
name1 xxx yyy zzz
name2 aaa bbb ccc
matchline_VAR
```

needs to become (if simple remove matchlines if not I can post-process to remove them):

```
VAR_name1 xxx yyy zzz
VAR_name2 aaa bbb ccc
```

Right now I am attempting in sed like so:

```
sed '/matchline_\(.*$\)/,/matchline_/ {s/^/\1_/g}'
```

It is instead just printing a 1 in front of the lines.

Perhaps I should also mention that this is part of a larger script to search through a text file and replace each instance of a shell variable $find (one line) with another shell variable $replace (multiple lines).  The current solution is:

```
awk -v find="$find" -v replace="$replace" '$0==find{$0=replace}1' file
```

The problem is that I need to append the first field in $find to each line of $replace
I tried:

```
awk -v find="$find" -v replace="$replace" '$0==find{$0="matchline_" $1 "_" replace}1'
```

but it only appends the name at the start of the multiline $replace.

Any help is appreciated,

John

Comment: sed is always the wrong tool for anything involving more than simple substitutions within a single line. It's not clear how this question relates to the other stuff you discuss - post some sample input and expected output of the overall problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F_ '$1=="matchline"{p = (!p)? $2 : ""; next} p{$0 = p FS $0} 1'
VAR_name1 xxx yyy zzz
VAR_name2 aaa bbb ccc
```

#### Explanation:

- `-F_` - Use field separator as underscore
- `$1=="matchline"` - execute the next block when field1 == "matchline"
- `p = (!p)? $2 : ""` - Toggle `p` between `$2` and `""` for above condition
- `p{$0 = p FS $0}` - If `p` is set then append `p` in whole line
- `1` - Default action to print each line

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response.  One thing I forgot to mention is that there are many lines above/below the matchline_VAR that need to be preserved unchanged.  The above code works great but it only prints between match lines (instead of printing all and appending only between matchlines).

Comment: I got it to work using:

    awk -F_ '$1=='matchline"{p = !(p)? $2 : ""; next} p{print p FS $0} !(p){print $0}'

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That will also work but a bit longer. You can use my updated command for same output.

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: It does not work well for my purpose, because now it will print the modified lines between matchline_ to matchline_ as well as unmodified (for example VAR_name1 xxx yyy zzz and name1 xxx yyy zzz). Using !(p) seems to make the two mutually exclusive.

Comment: No unmodified lines are printed **as is** without prefix using above command.

Comment: Well when I run it they are.  I had to change the p{$0 = p FS $0} 1' portion to p{$0 = p FS $0} !(p){print $0}' because the 1 was causing it to print incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'sub(/matchline_/,""){pfx=$0;next} {print pfx"_"$0}' file
VAR_name1 xxx yyy zzz
VAR_name2 aaa bbb ccc
```

Comment: I was not specific enough in my problem description.  But the above code inserts _ in all lines above the match, and inserts VAR_ on all lines below the match.  I would like to apply the pre-pending of lines only between /matchline_/ to /matchline_/, while leaving other parts of the text file untouched.