# Unknown command `>' with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have been trying to get through a sed command and have been unsuccessful.

Here is the sed command I am trying use;

```
sed -i "/<\/Testing>/i '<Tester>$VAR</Tester>'" filename
```

I keep getting `a unknown command: <`... I know why but there has been no luck. Single quotes is okay however the `$VAR` value isn't displayed, only the literal string.

For readers who are not very familiar with `sed`, this is a regular expression followed by an `i` command, not a sloppy mistype of a `"s%<Testing>%$VAR%"` substitution.  The `i` command inserts a string before the matching line.  In other words, when the input matches `</Testing>`, I want to add a snippet which describes a test case before the matching line.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a sample of your input and the desired output. Are you trying to perform a substitution?

Comment: You don't seem to supply enough information.  I can reproduce what you describe with `VAR=$'<hello>\n</hello>'; sed "/<\/Testing>/i '<Tester>$VAR</Tester>'" <<<$'<Testing>\nmoo</Testing>\n<end>\npoo\n</end>'` but there's an awful amount of guesswork about what you might be doing involved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search and replace shell variable with multiline shell variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912791/search-and-replace-shell-variable-with-multiline-shell-variable)

Answer (score 2):

If `$VAR` contains a newline, you need to backslash-escape it.

```
vnix$ VAR=$'<hello>\n</hello>'

vnix$ sed "/<\/Testing>/i '<Tester>$VAR</Tester>'" <<<$'<Testing>\nmoo</Testing>\n(end)'
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown command: `<'

vnix$ VAR=$'<hello>\\\n</hello>'

vnix$  sed "/<\/Testing>/i '<Tester>$VAR</Tester>'" <<<$'<Testing>\nmoo</Testing>\n(end)'
<Testing>
'<Tester><hello>
</hello></Tester>'
moo</Testing>
(end)
```

(I'm also guessing you don't actually want the single quotes around the substituted value, but that's obviously easy to fix.)

Comment: Nice detective work :) I guess you're implicitly assuming a version of sed that understands specifying the string to be inserted on the same line as the `i` (the standard says to use `i\ ` and put it on the next line).

Comment: If you need to make the substitution programmatically, you can use `nl=$'\n'; VAR="${VAR//$nl/\\n}"`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify certain command, like "s" (at the beginning):

```
sed -i "s/</Testing>/i '$VAR'" filename
```

Also, it would be better if you show example input and output

Comment: I don't think he's trying to perform any substitutions, but add a line following `</Testing>`.

Comment: The command (`i`) is immediately after the address (`/<\/Testing>/`), where it belongs.